# как открыть файл exe по заданому пути на пайтон

Tags: python, файлы, exe

Как сделать чтобы в нужный момент открывался exe файл из другой директории, использовать можно любые модули
вот код (если надо):

```
def login_sucess():
    global screen3
    screen3 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen3.title("Success")
    screen3.geometry("150x100")
    Label(screen3, text = "Login Sucess").pack()
    Button(screen3, text = "OK", command =delete2).pack()
    #тут открываеться файл по пути С:\User\Desktop\python\dist\main\main.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте класс [Popen](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-subprocess.html) модуля [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
subprocess.Popen(r"С:\User\Desktop\python\dist\main\main.exe")
```

Comment: Здравствуйте , ошибку не выдает но файл не запускаеться(

Comment: @denzzzy, "Changed in version 3.8: Popen can use os.posix_spawn() in some cases for better performance. On Windows Subsystem for Linux and QEMU User Emulation, Popen constructor using os.posix_spawn() no longer raise an exception on errors like missing program, but the child process fails with a non-zero returncode." (см. ссылку subprocess). То есть, возможно программа просто не найдена. Как я сразу заметил, у вас странный путь к рабочему столу. Вот, к примеру, мой: C:\Users\Shamus_Rezol\Desktop.

Comment: Попробуйте запомнить создаваемый процесс `process = subprocess.Popen(r"С:\User\Desktop\python\dist\main\main.exe")` и посмотреть возвращаемый код `print(process.poll())`. "but the child process fails with a non-zero returncode" - вероятно он ненулевой.